# View.post not speeding image processing up?

Tags: android, performance, image-processing

I'm trying to speed up my app by threading it. It an app that that places a fisheye effect on a bitmap. It works fine apart from it runs painfully slow. I've logged out some processing time of various methods and i've pinpointed it to the barrel() method in the filters class. this method takes a bitmap and loops through it distorting the pixels, this looping takes about 40 seconds to complete! i've tried AsyncTask but this takes 40+ seconds aswell. Lastly i've tried the View.post mechanism but this yields the same results. is there any way to speed this app up? Any ideas would be appreciated, thanks Matt.

.

```
public class TouchView extends View{


    private File tempFile;
    private byte[] imageArray;
    private Bitmap bgr;
    private Bitmap bm;
    private Bitmap bgr2 = null;;
    private Paint pTouch;
    private int centreX = 1;
    private int centreY = 1;
    private int radius = 50;
    private int Progress = 1;
    private static final String TAG = "*********TouchView";
    private Filters f = null;
    private boolean AsyncRunning = false;
   // private MyTask mt = null;



    public TouchView(Context context) {
        super(context);
       // TouchView(context, null);
    }




    public TouchView(Context context, AttributeSet attr) {
        super(context,attr);


       ........... code to get bitmap from camera shot.........

        bgr2 = Bitmap.createBitmap(bm.getWidth(), bm.getHeight(), bm.getConfig());



       f = new Filters();





    }// end of touchView constructor


    public void findCirclePixels(){ 


              new Thread(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    float prog = (float)Progress/150000;

                final Bitmap bgr3 = f.barrel(bgr,prog);
                  TouchView.this.post(new Runnable() {
                    public void run() {
                      TouchView.this.bgr2 = bgr3;
                      TouchView.this.invalidate();
                    }
                  });
                }
              }).start();





        }// end of changePixel()








    public void initSlider(final HorizontalSlider slider)
    {
      //  Log.e(TAG, "******setting up slider*********** ");
        slider.setOnProgressChangeListener(changeListener);
    }



    private OnProgressChangeListener changeListener = new OnProgressChangeListener() {


        @Override
        public void onProgressChanged(View v, int progress) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub


              setProgress(progress);
            //TouchView.this.Progress = progress;


        }
    };



    @Override
    public void onDraw(Canvas canvas){
        super.onDraw(canvas);


        canvas.drawBitmap(bgr2, 0, 0, null);




    }//end of onDraw




    protected void setProgress(int progress2) {
        //Log.e(TAG, "***********in SETPROGRESS");
        this.Progress = progress2;



        findCirclePixels();
        invalidate();


    }




}
```

.

```
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.util.Log;

class Filters{
    float xscale;
    float yscale;
    float xshift;
    float yshift;
    int [] s;
    private String TAG = "Filters";
    long getRadXStart = 0;
    long getRadXEnd = 0;
    long startSample = 0;
    long endSample = 0;
    public Filters(){

        Log.e(TAG, "***********inside filter constructor");
    }

    public Bitmap barrel (Bitmap input, float k){
        //Log.e(TAG, "***********INSIDE BARREL METHOD ");

        float centerX=input.getWidth()/2; //center of distortion
        float centerY=input.getHeight()/2;

        int width = input.getWidth(); //image bounds
        int height = input.getHeight();

        Bitmap dst = Bitmap.createBitmap(width, height,input.getConfig() ); //output pic
       // Log.e(TAG, "***********dst bitmap created ");
          xshift = calc_shift(0,centerX-1,centerX,k);

          float newcenterX = width-centerX;
          float xshift_2 = calc_shift(0,newcenterX-1,newcenterX,k);

          yshift = calc_shift(0,centerY-1,centerY,k);

          float newcenterY = height-centerY;
          float yshift_2 = calc_shift(0,newcenterY-1,newcenterY,k);

          xscale = (width-xshift-xshift_2)/width;
        //  Log.e(TAG, "***********xscale ="+xscale);
          yscale = (height-yshift-yshift_2)/height;
        //  Log.e(TAG, "***********yscale ="+yscale);
        //  Log.e(TAG, "***********filter.barrel() about to loop through bm");
          /*for(int j=0;j<dst.getHeight();j++){
              for(int i=0;i<dst.getWidth();i++){
                float x = getRadialX((float)i,(float)j,centerX,centerY,k);
                float y = getRadialY((float)i,(float)j,centerX,centerY,k);
                sampleImage(input,x,y);
                int color = ((s[1]&0x0ff)<<16)|((s[2]&0x0ff)<<8)|(s[3]&0x0ff);
    //            System.out.print(i+" "+j+" \\");

                dst.setPixel(i, j, color);

              }
            }*/

          int origPixel;
          long startLoop = System.currentTimeMillis();
          for(int j=0;j<dst.getHeight();j++){
              for(int i=0;i<dst.getWidth();i++){
                 origPixel= input.getPixel(i,j);
                 getRadXStart = System.currentTimeMillis();
                float x = getRadialX((float)j,(float)i,centerX,centerY,k);
                getRadXEnd= System.currentTimeMillis();

                float y = getRadialY((float)j,(float)i,centerX,centerY,k);

                sampleImage(input,x,y);

                int color = ((s[1]&0x0ff)<<16)|((s[2]&0x0ff)<<8)|(s[3]&0x0ff);
    //            System.out.print(i+" "+j+" \\");

                if( Math.sqrt( Math.pow(i - centerX, 2) + ( Math.pow(j - centerY, 2) ) ) <= 150 ){
                dst.setPixel(i, j, color);
                }else{
                    dst.setPixel(i,j,origPixel);
                }
              }
            }
          long endLoop = System.currentTimeMillis();
          long loopDuration = endLoop - startLoop;
          long radXDuration = getRadXEnd - getRadXStart;
          long sampleDur = endSample - startSample;

          Log.e(TAG, "sample method took "+sampleDur+"ms");
          Log.e(TAG, "getRadialX took "+radXDuration+"ms");
          Log.e(TAG, "loop took "+loopDuration+"ms");

        //  Log.e(TAG, "***********filter.barrel()  looped through bm about to return dst bm");
        return dst;
    }

    void sampleImage(Bitmap arr, float idx0, float idx1)
    {
         startSample = System.currentTimeMillis();
        s = new int [4];
      if(idx0<0 || idx1<0 || idx0>(arr.getHeight()-1) || idx1>(arr.getWidth()-1)){
        s[0]=0;
        s[1]=0;
        s[2]=0;
        s[3]=0;
        return;
      }

      float idx0_fl=(float) Math.floor(idx0);
      float idx0_cl=(float) Math.ceil(idx0);
      float idx1_fl=(float) Math.floor(idx1);
      float idx1_cl=(float) Math.ceil(idx1);

      int [] s1 = getARGB(arr,(int)idx0_fl,(int)idx1_fl);
      int [] s2 = getARGB(arr,(int)idx0_fl,(int)idx1_cl);
      int [] s3 = getARGB(arr,(int)idx0_cl,(int)idx1_cl);
      int [] s4 = getARGB(arr,(int)idx0_cl,(int)idx1_fl);

      float x = idx0 - idx0_fl;
      float y = idx1 - idx1_fl;

      s[0]= (int) (s1[0]*(1-x)*(1-y) + s2[0]*(1-x)*y + s3[0]*x*y + s4[0]*x*(1-y));
      s[1]= (int) (s1[1]*(1-x)*(1-y) + s2[1]*(1-x)*y + s3[1]*x*y + s4[1]*x*(1-y));
      s[2]= (int) (s1[2]*(1-x)*(1-y) + s2[2]*(1-x)*y + s3[2]*x*y + s4[2]*x*(1-y));
      s[3]= (int) (s1[3]*(1-x)*(1-y) + s2[3]*(1-x)*y + s3[3]*x*y + s4[3]*x*(1-y));

      endSample = System.currentTimeMillis();
    }

    int [] getARGB(Bitmap buf,int x, int y){

        int rgb = buf.getPixel(y, x); // Returns by default ARGB.
        int [] scalar = new int[4];
        scalar[0] = (rgb >>> 24) & 0xFF;
        scalar[1] = (rgb >>> 16) & 0xFF;
        scalar[2] = (rgb >>> 8) & 0xFF;
        scalar[3] = (rgb >>> 0) & 0xFF;
        return scalar;
    }

    float getRadialX(float x,float y,float cx,float cy,float k){

      x = (x*xscale+xshift);
      y = (y*yscale+yshift);
      float res = x+((x-cx)*k*((x-cx)*(x-cx)+(y-cy)*(y-cy)));
      return res;
    }

    float getRadialY(float x,float y,float cx,float cy,float k){

      x = (x*xscale+xshift);
      y = (y*yscale+yshift);
      float res = y+((y-cy)*k*((x-cx)*(x-cx)+(y-cy)*(y-cy)));
      return res;
    }

    float thresh = 1;

    float calc_shift(float x1,float x2,float cx,float k){

      float x3 = (float)(x1+(x2-x1)*0.5);
      float res1 = x1+((x1-cx)*k*((x1-cx)*(x1-cx)));
      float res3 = x3+((x3-cx)*k*((x3-cx)*(x3-cx)));

      if(res1>-thresh && res1 < thresh)
        return x1;
      if(res3<0){
        return calc_shift(x3,x2,cx,k);
      }
      else{
        return calc_shift(x1,x3,cx,k);
      }
    }



}// end of filters class
```

Comment: Use Traceview to get a more complete picture of where your time is being spent. http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/debugging/debugging-tracing.html

Comment: @CommonsWare hi, i've created a trace file called barrel.trace and pulled it on to my desktop. How do i start the traceview tool? i've tried the sdk/tools folder and clicked on traceview but that window just closes

Comment: Open a Command Prompt. Switch to your `tools/` directory. Run `traceview ...`, where `...` is the path to your trace file. Or, if you are using Eclipse, Traceview is a perspective that you can open.

Comment: @CommonsWare hi ok i've got the Traceview working(not in eclipse though, through cmd). I can see that a new thread has been created to handle the image processing stuff as expected. the majority of that thread is spent in sample() method setiing/getting/checking pixels. So how can i optimize this app. Is this as fast(40secs) Android can process a bitmap(3.2megapixel)? Is it a case of perhaps cutting down the ammount of pixels to loop through? Before i try the latter i still think there is an underlying problem here as 40 secs is far to long and i don't want to overlook it before optimizing it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Floating-point math sucks in general, on pretty much every computer ever created. However, it really sucks on devices that lack floating-point co-processor support, such as half the Android devices out there. So, get rid of *every bit of floating point math*, such as:

- You do not need to run integers through floating-point `ceil()` and `floor()` methods
- You do not need to calculate `sqrt()` to compare against `150` rather than skipping the `sqrt()` and comparing against `22500`
- You do not need a floating-point `pow()` to compute the square of something; instead, use the advanced mathematical operation known as "multiplication"
- I doubt that half-pixels will matter a ton in your calculations, so probably you do not need `centerX` and `centerY` to be `float` values
- And so on

In a pinch, you may need to use tricks like the Google Maps add-on for Android uses. Ordinarily, you would think of latitude and longitude in decimal degrees, but that means lots of floating-point math. Google Maps uses latitude and longitude in microdegrees (10^6 times degrees), to be able to do all the calculations in fixed-point math yet retain reasonable accuracy.

Whether all of this will get performance down to whatever you feel is reasonable, I cannot say. However, you should make sure make sure *your* code is of reasonable quality, before you start complaining about the quality of Android's code, as you did in your last comment.

Comment: ok thanks for the input. Regarding Android's code i wasn't meaning anything derogatory at all, on the contrary i was highlighting that i thought there was a problem with my code as 40 secs is indeed too slow and that i was positive that Android can process a bitmap faster. Basically i was wondering if i had implemented my code correctly with regard to Android lifecycle, event calls, etc etc maybe there is something I have done wrong that i rectify before optimizing the app. hope that makes sense. thanks

Comment: @turtleboy: Ah, OK. In the end, it's possible that to get to the performance you seek, you will need to use the NDK for C/C++ code (or Renderscript Compute on Honeycomb). But I think de-`float`-ing your code will go a long way towards helping.

Comment: ok. i'm not sure you if you meant me to do the following, but i've made all the floats an int in the filters class and done away with math.ciel(). it has shed 5 seconds off the processing time but the effect no longer appears on the bitmap.

Comment: @turtleboy: Then fix your algorithm, while sticking with integer (fixed-point) math wherever possible. Fixed-point math is not especially hard. For example, most games (Android and otherwise) use fixed-point math to minimize overhead, so valuable CPU time can be spent on other things like game physics and AI. If fixed-point math confuses you, consider opening fresh StackOverflow questions -- tagged with the `java` tag -- to help you convert your algorithm to avoid as much floating-point as possible.

Comment: ok thanks for your time, you've made a few things clearer now. Matt